# Should I lock a file before I read it in C#

Tags: c#, file, locking

Do I need to lock an xml file in C# before I read it and if I am never writing back to that file.

If I use,

```
   using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(
                "myXmlFile.xml", 
                FileMode.Open, 
                FileAccess.Read, 
                FileShare.Read))
```

is there any chance that in a multithreaded environment, two users can access the same file at the same time and get a lock error?

Comment: What do you mean by "lock a file" ? What exactly you mean by lock?

Comment: You are already locking the file. `FileShare.Read` will allow other processes to open the file for reading, but not for writing. If another process tries to open the file for writing, it will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to lock the file before you read it. The only reason you would need to lock it is if you wanted to be sure that the file would not be altered while you are reading it.

Yes if you lock the file with that code then other users can get a lock error if they try and write to the file or read the file with read/write privleges. It is quite common with the programs i work on.

You should not lock files unless you actually need to.

if you dont want to lock the file then use the ReadWrite share enum.

```
   using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(
                "myXmlFile.xml", 
                FileMode.Open, 
                FileAccess.Read, 
                FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

Comment: To add to this, a case where you may need to lock a file would be if you were writing to it

Comment: "The only reason you would need to lock it is if you wanted to be sure that the file would not be altered while you are reading it." So "only" 99.9% of the time then?

Comment: @JonHanna Not really, Depending on what the file is it may or may not matter. If you're reading a text file then if you write you code correctly it wont matter, but if you're reading a picture file then it will be corrupted if its altered while you are reading it. It depends on the situation. Personally i always try and write my code to support the file being altered. No need to potentially break another program by locking the file.

Comment: And then what is one meant to do with the results? They aren't even likely to be well-formed XML, never mind meaningful if they were.

Comment: @JonHanna as i said it depends on the file type. Sometimes you can handle it, sometimes you cant. You need to take it on a case by case basis.

Comment: We've already determined that the file type is some sort of XML file type. Having what you read suddenly not be well-formed is not going to be easily manageable the majority of the times with XML.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should lock it precisely as you have done there.

Note that the locking you have here does not prevent reading by other threads or processes (which wouldn't cause you difficulty), but only prevent writing. To prevent reading as well (because you are going to change the file) use `FileShare.None`.

Go with `FileShare.ReadWrite` only if you are going to be able to tolerate the file being changed as you write it either implicitly by passing it to something that can handle this (not the case of just about any XML parsing approaches in .NET) or explicitly by catching the problems caused.